# Close all the items in accordion menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I need all the menus to be closed by default in accordion menu.
Here is the script which I am using, here 1st tab will be opened by default. How do I get every tab closed by default

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('#accrdion').accordion();          
        </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using the [jQuery-UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/), you can collapse all by enabling `collapsible`, and then using the method [`activate`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#method-activate) with a value of `false`, like this:

```
// construct the accordion
$('#accrdion').accordion({
    collapsible: true
});

// collapse all somewhere else
$('#accrdion').accordion('activate', false);
```